# Build a dataframe from .pgn (string row) using re

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a single .pgn (Portable Game Notation) of a large number of chess games. The games are contained in the file like this:

```
    [Event"FIDE World Cup 2017"]
    [Site "Tbilisi GEO"]
    [Date "2017.09.05"]
    [Round "1.1"]
    [White "Carlsen, Magnus"]
    [Black "Balogun, Oluwafemi"]
    [Result "1-0"]
    [WhiteTitle "GM"]
    [BlackTitle "FM"]
    [WhiteElo "2822"]
    [BlackElo "2255"]
    [ECO "B00"]
    [Opening "King's pawn opening"]
    [WhiteFideId "1503014"]
    [BlackFideId "8501246"]
    [EventDate "2017.09.03"]

    1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Qe2 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bg7 6. O-O Bg4 7. c3 O-O         
    8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 e5 10. Rd1 Qe8 11. d5 Ne7 12. Qe2 Nh5 13. Bb5 Qc8 
    14. Na3 a6 15. Ba4 f5 16. Bc2 f4 17. Qg4 Qxg4 18. hxg4 Nf6 19. g5 Nd7 
    20. Nc4 b6 21. b4 h6 22. gxh6 Bxh6 23. g4 Nf6 24. f3 Bg5 25. Kg2 Kg7 
    26. a4 Bh4 27. Bd2 g5 28. Rh1 Ng6 29. Kf1 Rh8 30. Ke2 Bg3 31. a5 b5 32. 
    Na3 Ne7 33. c4 c6 34. dxc6 Nxc6 35. Bc3 Rxh1 36. Rxh1 bxc4 37. Nxc4 Rb8 
    38. Nxd6 Kg6 39. Nf5 1-0

    [Event "FIDE World Cup 2018"]    
    etc...
```

I would like to create a data frame with this data where the column titles are the words repeated in the brackets such as "Event" or "Site" and the data is the one in the quotation marks. Also, I would like to include the moves of course, which are not in quotation marks nor brackets...

I think I could use re module to build first a dictionary and after that convert the dictionary into a data frame but I am not capable of doing so. Could you please help me?

```
Nested_dict = { 
  "Game1": {"Event" : "FIDE World Cup 2017" , "Site " : "Tbilisi GEO" , "moves": "1. e4 d6"}
  "Game2": {"Event" : "FIDE World Cup 2018" , "Site " : "Astana GEO" , "moves": "1. e4 e5"}
}
```

I have made myself able to get all they "values" of the dictionary, but I can´t get the "keys":

```
import re

with open('lichess_game.pgn', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = ((line.split(",") for line in stripped if line))
    for line in lines:
        stripped=str(line)
        stripped = (stripped.replace("]",""))
        stripped=stripped.replace("[","")
        values=str(re.findall(r'["](.*?)["]',stripped)) #Is there someting like re.finall(not(condition)? I mean, find everthing that is not inside this condition
        values = (values.replace("]",'"')) #Could I replace two diferent characters at the same time?
        values=values.replace("[",'"')
        key=stripped.replace((values),"") #this is me trying the get the key from the string minus the values....
        print(values) #Right!
        print(key)    #Nope
```

The final table of the data frame would be with all the games in rows and each column the information of each game, for example, column 1 would be Event and the first row "FIDE World Cup 2017"

```
Event               Site    Date       Round White           Black  
FIDE World Cup 2017 Tbilisi 2017.09.05 1.1   Carlsen, Magnus Balogun, Oluwafemi
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: inside `for`-loop you should first check if line is not empty and if it starts with `[` to decide what to do with this row. Rows with moves need different work.

Comment: for first part you don't need regex - you can remove `[]` using slicing `line[1:-1]`  and later `split(" ", 1)` will split it on first space to get two values - ie. `Event` and `"FIDE World Cup 2017"`. On second value you can use `[1:-1]` to remove `" "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use empty line and variable `moves` to recognize if it is start of lines with moves or start of lines with new game.

For game I use `[1:-1]` to remove `[ ]` and later `" "`. I use `split(' ', 1)` to split text inside `[ ]` into two elements which I use as key and value in dict.

For moves I keep them in list and when it starts new game then I concatenate them and put in dictionary. When it starts new game then I clear dict for new row and list for new moves.

I use module `json` only to display dictionary in more readable way. It is not needed to work with data.

```
text = '''[Event "FIDE World Cup 2017"]
    [Site "Tbilisi GEO"]
    [Date "2017.09.05"]
    [Round "1.1"]
    [White "Carlsen, Magnus"]
    [Black "Balogun, Oluwafemi"]
    [Result "1-0"]
    [WhiteTitle "GM"]
    [BlackTitle "FM"]
    [WhiteElo "2822"]
    [BlackElo "2255"]
    [ECO "B00"]
    [Opening "King's pawn opening"]
    [WhiteFideId "1503014"]
    [BlackFideId "8501246"]
    [EventDate "2017.09.03"]

    1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Qe2 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bg7 6. O-O Bg4 7. c3 O-O         
    8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 e5 10. Rd1 Qe8 11. d5 Ne7 12. Qe2 Nh5 13. Bb5 Qc8 
    14. Na3 a6 15. Ba4 f5 16. Bc2 f4 17. Qg4 Qxg4 18. hxg4 Nf6 19. g5 Nd7 
    20. Nc4 b6 21. b4 h6 22. gxh6 Bxh6 23. g4 Nf6 24. f3 Bg5 25. Kg2 Kg7 
    26. a4 Bh4 27. Bd2 g5 28. Rh1 Ng6 29. Kf1 Rh8 30. Ke2 Bg3 31. a5 b5 32. 
    Na3 Ne7 33. c4 c6 34. dxc6 Nxc6 35. Bc3 Rxh1 36. Rxh1 bxc4 37. Nxc4 Rb8 
    38. Nxd6 Kg6 39. Nf5 1-0

[Event "FIDE World Cup 2017"]
    [Site "Tbilisi GEO"]
    [Date "2017.09.05"]
    [Round "1.1"]
    [White "Carlsen, Magnus"]
    [Black "Balogun, Oluwafemi"]
    [Result "1-0"]
    [WhiteTitle "GM"]
    [BlackTitle "FM"]
    [WhiteElo "2822"]
    [BlackElo "2255"]
    [ECO "B00"]
    [Opening "King's pawn opening"]
    [WhiteFideId "1503014"]
    [BlackFideId "8501246"]
    [EventDate "2017.09.03"]

    1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Qe2 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bg7 6. O-O Bg4 7. c3 O-O         
    8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 e5 10. Rd1 Qe8 11. d5 Ne7 12. Qe2 Nh5 13. Bb5 Qc8 
    14. Na3 a6 15. Ba4 f5 16. Bc2 f4 17. Qg4 Qxg4 18. hxg4 Nf6 19. g5 Nd7 
    20. Nc4 b6 21. b4 h6 22. gxh6 Bxh6 23. g4 Nf6 24. f3 Bg5 25. Kg2 Kg7 
    26. a4 Bh4 27. Bd2 g5 28. Rh1 Ng6 29. Kf1 Rh8 30. Ke2 Bg3 31. a5 b5 32. 
    Na3 Ne7 33. c4 c6 34. dxc6 Nxc6 35. Bc3 Rxh1 36. Rxh1 bxc4 37. Nxc4 Rb8 
    38. Nxd6 Kg6 39. Nf5 1-0    
    '''

all_rows = dict()

# create dict/list for first game
row = dict()
moves = False
moves_lines = list()
game = 1

for line in text.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        if moves:
            moves_lines.append(line)
        elif line.startswith('['):
            line = line[1:-1]
            parts = line.split(' ', 1)
            parts[1] = parts[1][1:-1]
            row[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    else:
        # if empty line then it is beginning of moves or beginning of new game
        if not moves:
            # start lines with moves
            moves = True
        else:
            # end of lines with moves - so it is time to add it to dict
            row['moves'] = ' '.join(moves_lines)
            all_rows['Game{}'.format(game)] = row

            # create dict/list for next game
            row = dict()
            moves = False
            moves_lines = list()
            game += 1

# after loop there can be last row to fill            
if row: 
   row['moves'] = ' '.join(moves_lines)
   all_rows['Game{}'.format(game)] = row

import json
print(json.dumps(all_rows, indent=2))
```

Result (formated by `json`)

```
{
  "Game1": {
    "Event": "FIDE World Cup 2017",
    "Site": "Tbilisi GEO",
    "Date": "2017.09.05",
    "Round": "1.1",
    "White": "Carlsen, Magnus",
    "Black": "Balogun, Oluwafemi",
    "Result": "1-0",
    "WhiteTitle": "GM",
    "BlackTitle": "FM",
    "WhiteElo": "2822",
    "BlackElo": "2255",
    "ECO": "B00",
    "Opening": "King's pawn opening",
    "WhiteFideId": "1503014",
    "BlackFideId": "8501246",
    "EventDate": "2017.09.03",
    "moves": "1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Qe2 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bg7 6. O-O Bg4 7. c3 O-O 8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 e5 10. Rd1 Qe8 11. d5 Ne7 12. Qe2 Nh5 13. Bb5 Qc8 14. Na3 a6 15. Ba4 f5 16. Bc2 f4 17. Qg4 Qxg4 18. hxg4 Nf6 19. g5 Nd7 20. Nc4 b6 21. b4 h6 22. gxh6 Bxh6 23. g4 Nf6 24. f3 Bg5 25. Kg2 Kg7 26. a4 Bh4 27. Bd2 g5 28. Rh1 Ng6 29. Kf1 Rh8 30. Ke2 Bg3 31. a5 b5 32. Na3 Ne7 33. c4 c6 34. dxc6 Nxc6 35. Bc3 Rxh1 36. Rxh1 bxc4 37. Nxc4 Rb8 38. Nxd6 Kg6 39. Nf5 1-0"
  },
  "Game2": {
    "Event": "FIDE World Cup 2017",
    "Site": "Tbilisi GEO",
    "Date": "2017.09.05",
    "Round": "1.1",
    "White": "Carlsen, Magnus",
    "Black": "Balogun, Oluwafemi",
    "Result": "1-0",
    "WhiteTitle": "GM",
    "BlackTitle": "FM",
    "WhiteElo": "2822",
    "BlackElo": "2255",
    "ECO": "B00",
    "Opening": "King's pawn opening",
    "WhiteFideId": "1503014",
    "BlackFideId": "8501246",
    "EventDate": "2017.09.03",
    "moves": "1. e4 d6 2. d4 g6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Qe2 Nc6 5. Nf3 Bg7 6. O-O Bg4 7. c3 O-O 8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 e5 10. Rd1 Qe8 11. d5 Ne7 12. Qe2 Nh5 13. Bb5 Qc8 14. Na3 a6 15. Ba4 f5 16. Bc2 f4 17. Qg4 Qxg4 18. hxg4 Nf6 19. g5 Nd7 20. Nc4 b6 21. b4 h6 22. gxh6 Bxh6 23. g4 Nf6 24. f3 Bg5 25. Kg2 Kg7 26. a4 Bh4 27. Bd2 g5 28. Rh1 Ng6 29. Kf1 Rh8 30. Ke2 Bg3 31. a5 b5 32. Na3 Ne7 33. c4 c6 34. dxc6 Nxc6 35. Bc3 Rxh1 36. Rxh1 bxc4 37. Nxc4 Rb8 38. Nxd6 Kg6 39. Nf5 1-0"
  }
}
```